# C# Setting combobox text when form loads

Tags: c#, combobox, registry

When my program loads I read a value from the registry and set a read only combo box to that value however when loaded the combobox shows the item before it in the collection. I'm using the code below to set the text.

```
RegistryKey OurKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
OurKey = OurKey.OpenSubKey("Software\\test",true);
type = OurKey.GetValue("Type").ToString();
cboType.Text = type;
```

How should I set the combobox to the value I've read from the registry?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You find the value by it's text value, and then select the returned list item by it's index:

```
RegistryKey OurKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
OurKey = OurKey.OpenSubKey("Software\\test",true);
type = OurKey.GetValue("Type").ToString();

ListItem selectItem = new ListItem();
selectItem = cboType.Items.FindByText(type);

if (selectItem != null)
{
   cboType.SelectedIndex = cboType.Items.IndexOf(selectItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it into the items collection:

```
int index = cboType.Items.IndexOf(type);
if (index < 0)
{
    cboType.Items.Insert(0, type);
    cboType.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
else
    cboType.SelectedIndex = index;
```

Comment: Hi, The value is already in the items collection, how would your code differ?

Comment: Setting text property not always select appropriate item from collection. So if 'type' is in collection, and your combobox is read-only it is better to set SelectedIndex instead of Text.